# Python Equivalent to Javascript index assignment

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

Original code in JS:

```js
// applying crossover
for (let i = cxpoint1; i < cxpoint2; i++) {
  let temp1 = ind1[i]
  let temp2 = ind2[i]

  ind1[i]         = temp2
  ind1[p1[temp2]] = temp1

  ind2[i]         = temp1
  ind2[p2[temp1]] = temp2

  return [ind1, ind2]
```

New to JS and wondering what is happening on this line:

```html
ind1[p1[temp2]] = temp1
```

Trying to understand so I can make an equivalent function in Python.

I understand the assignment, however obviously in Python you cannot use double brackets as shown on the line above. If someone could tell me the concept, I should be able to apply it to my situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you cannot use double brackets in python? if you have that `temp2 = 1` `p1 = [2,3,4]`  and you do `ind1[p1[temp2]] = temp1` this will be equivalent of doing `ind1[p1[1]] = temp1` which will be equivalent of doing `ind1[3] = temp1`

Comment: What python code have you tried? What results did you get?

Comment: on that line you are just taking index from p1 array and updfdating that index value to temp1

Comment: Hi mountainwater, questions like "what does this code do?" are not really within scope of this site. To get an answer for your question, provide a minimal example in JS that shows the desired behavior, and what you've tried in python that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully understand the code one would need to know how the arrays p1 and p2 look like, but I assume they are integer-arrays. You select an integer from that array in the inner statement that then is the index for the outer statement.

It works exactly the same in python:

```
ind1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p1 = [3, 1, 2]
print(ind1[p1[0]])
# -> 4
```

In this example the inner statement resolves to 3 (first element in the p1-list) and the outer statement then resolves to 4 (fourth element in the ind1-list.

Comment: Thanks man, understood the concept now with this simple example. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing magical going on here.

```
ind1[p1[temp2]]
```

`p1[temp2]` resolves to some value, let's call it `a`.  So the expression then becomes `ind1[a]`.